# Splitting a time frame by months

Tags: sql, qlikview

I have a two timestamps `start_datetime` and `end_datetime` that represent the time I started work on a project and the time I finished work on the project, respectively. The timestamps span a two month period. I want to split them so that I can show (in chart form) how much of my time was spend in the first month and how much time was spent in the second month. For example, if I started a project at 0:00:00 on March 31st and ended it at 0:00:00 on April 2nd, I want to show that 50% of the work occurred in March and 50% in April. Is this possible?

As an add-on, can I do this if the project spanned more than 2 months? What about 3 or 4? or 13?

Would the manipulation affect time periods that spanned less than a month?

Comment: What database are you using (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc.)?

Comment: It's a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0):

The intervalmatch script function is what you are looking for. Combined with a master calendar to allow you to count the dates will let you make the table you want. I just autogenerate one here, you could use any method to create it.

```
Intervals:
LOAD ID, 
 StartDate, 
 EndDate
FROM
[Q:\Stack Exchange\Calls.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet2);

let zDateMin=42000;
let zDateMax=42100;

DATES:
LOAD
    Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1) as [DATE],
    year( Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1)) as YEAR,
    month( Date($(zDateMin) + IterNo() - 1)) as MONTH
AUTOGENERATE 1
WHILE $(zDateMin)+IterNo()-1<= $(zDateMax);

INTERVAL:   
IntervalMatch (DATE) load StartDate, EndDate resident Intervals;

left join (DATES) load * resident INTERVAL; drop table INTERVAL;
```

Then you can make this table and get those percentages

[image: Intervals]